# How to link source of traffic with JS function

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, cookies, session-cookies

Please now i use this Javascript function

```
function getCookie(name) {
  const value = `; ${document.cookie}`;
  const parts = value.split(`; ${name}=`);
  if (parts.length === 2) return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
}

function setLastAccess() {
  const date = new Date();
  const expireMs = 0.5 * 60 * 1000; // number of minutes
  date.setTime(date.getTime() + expireMs);
  document.cookie = `lastAccess=${new Date().getTime()};expires=${date.toUTCString()};path=/`;
}

if (!getCookie('lastAccess')) {
  window.location.href = "http://google.com";
  setLastAccess(); // set your last access at the end
} else {
  setTimeout(function() {
    document.getElementById('button-login').click();
  }, 1000);
}
```

but now i want to make this function not to work if the website traffic is not from Google chrome or Firefox browsers.How to make that ?
And if the traffic is from any other browsers just give the user a message .

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at [user agents](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/User-Agent), but it is [not recommended to serve different content to different browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent), although in your case it's only a function so it may be ok. If you really want to check for Chrome or Firefox, you can do this:

```js
if (/chrome|firefox/gi.test(window.navigator.userAgent)) {
  // chrome or firefox
} else {
  alert("not using chrome or firefox")
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but when i run it  if (/chrome|firefox/gi.test(window.navigator.userAgent)) {
        window.location.href = "https://google.com";
    } else {
  alert("not using chrome or firefox")
}

Comment: it redirects the user even if i run it from Microsoft Edge

Comment: Hello pro thanks for your help it worked when i deleted "gi" and added ) to the code .

Comment: but now it give the alert even if iam using google chrome.

Comment: You need at least the `i` flag on the regex to make it case insensitive. It looks like most user agents have the word "chrome" in them. Try this example instead https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/navigator.